# Renaming Pictures using GPS Position from exiftool

Tags: automation, geolocation, gps, photos, exiftool

i would like to automaticly rename picture using the GPS position from / with exiftool.

Image names are like IM_25459.jpg and i would like to rename them e.g. Date_CountryCode_City_Street.jpg

I allready found a way to convert the GPS Data using GeoSetter and fill the IPTC. But the IPTC data only contains country and citiy information and i still miss the street information.

So is there a way to extract the exact or near by street name?

Answer (score 1):

Not without some external scripting of some sort.  For example, you could use exiftool to extract the GPS coordinates, then use create an url to access [Google Maps Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) using something like Curl and then parse the street address out of the resulting json data.